# exit of if in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

For example if the sentence `if($cocienteart52 >41.85)` is `TRUE` exit of all the next and so on , with the second one

```
if($cargasreprobadas == 0 && $cargatotal <= $cargamaxima)
```

is `TRUE` exit of the next two if,

```
if($cocienteart52 > 41.85){
    echo "NO PROCEDE POR EXCEDER TIEMPO<br><br>";
}

if($cargasreprobadas == 0 && $cargatotal <= $cargamaxima){
    echo "PROCEDE<br><br>";
}

if($cargasreprobadas != 0 && $cargatotal <= 41.85){
    echo "PROCEDE<br><br>";
}

if($cargatotal > 41.85){
    echo "NO PROCEDE POR EXCEDER CARGA<br><br>";
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little confused by your wording.

Comment: @ed9uardo0 aren't you looking for `return` ? You want to jump out of currently executing file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or how about this:

```
function echoThings($cocienteart52, $cargasreprobadas, $cargatotal, $cargamaxima){
    if($cocienteart52 > 41.85){
        echo "NO PROCEDE POR EXCEDER TIEMPO<br><br>";
        return;
    }

    if($cargasreprobadas == 0 && $cargatotal <= $cargamaxima){
        echo "PROCEDE<br><br>";
        return;
    }

    if($cargasreprobadas != 0 && $cargatotal <= 41.85){
        echo "PROCEDE<br><br>";
        return;
    }

    if($cargatotal > 41.85){
        echo "NO PROCEDE POR EXCEDER CARGA<br><br>";
        return;
    }
}

echoThings($cocienteart52, $cargasreprobadas, $cargatotal, $cargamaxima);
```

Or perhaps this:

```
function echoThings($cocienteart52, $cargasreprobadas, $cargatotal, $cargamaxima){
    echo "NO PROCEDE POR EXCEDER TIEMPO<br><br>";
    if($cocienteart52 > 41.85) return;

    echo "PROCEDE<br><br>";
    if($cargasreprobadas == 0 && $cargatotal <= $cargamaxima) return;

    echo "PROCEDE<br><br>";
    if($cargasreprobadas != 0 && $cargatotal <= 41.85) return;

    echo "NO PROCEDE POR EXCEDER CARGA<br><br>";
    if($cargatotal > 41.85) return;
}

echoThings($cocienteart52, $cargasreprobadas, $cargatotal, $cargamaxima);
```

Comment: the result is corret :),but there are many undefined variables,how can fix it i'm new in php :(                                                  Notice: Undefined variable: cocienteart52 in C:\xampp\htdocs\formtronco.php on line 474

Notice: Undefined variable: cargasreprobadas in C:\xampp\htdocs\formtronco.php on line 479

Notice: Undefined variable: cargamaxima in C:\xampp\htdocs\formtronco.php on line 479

Notice: Undefined variable: cargatotal in C:\xampp\htdocs\formtronco.php on line 479

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [exit](https://www.php.net/exit).

```
if (statement) {
    exit('The script has been terminated.');
}
```

Comment: but the problem  is that I dont want to exit of all the script,i prefer exit just of the if sentences.any clue about that :/

Comment: The other poster has what you need. When you say exit and if statements, to me that means you're wanting to end the script right there. Sorry for the confusion.